# How to check state of a switch toggle in Selenium using c#

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, specflow

I am trying to validate if a switch is 'on or 'off' using selenium but I cant seem to get it right. The toggle is set to the on position on loading the webpage but filter results in a table when it is off etc. It works fine i just check get my selenium tests to get its current state.

1. element.Selected; always returns false (regards of toggle position)
2. element.Enabled; always returns true (regards of toggle position)
3. string test = myToggle.GetAttribute("class"); returns the text "slider round" which doesn't help
4. string test1 = myToggle.GetAttribute("checked"); is null
5. string test2 = myToggle.GetAttribute("value"); is null

Here is the code:

```
<label class="switch">
<input type="checkbox" id="myToggle" checked />
<span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
```

The code that checks the toggle position and loads the table data:

```
   if (Amt == currentAmt ) {
    if ($("#myToggle").prop("checked") == true) {
        loadMyProducts('NAN', $("#total").val());
    }
```

My test at the moment looks like this

> ```
>     [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//*[@id='divTestAcc']/div[1]/p[9]/label/span")]
>   public IWebElement myToggle { get; set; }
>
>     public Boolean CheckMyToogleIsOnorOFF()
>     {
>         string test = myToggle.GetAttribute("class");
>         Console.Write("checking "+ test);
>
>         // string test1 = myToggle.GetAttribute("checked");
>         //string test2 = myToggle.GetProperty("checked");
>         // .Selected always returns false
>         // .Enables always returns true 
>
>         Boolean result;
>         result = myToggle.Enabled;
>         bool result1 = myToggle.Selected;
>
>         if (result == true)
>         {
>             Console.WriteLine("My toggle is enabled");
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             Console.WriteLine("My toggle is not enabled");
>         }
>         return result;
>     }
> ```

Comment: If your string test = myToggle.GetAttribute("class"); returns the text "slider round" then you are trying to verify span element instead of checkbox element. choose correct element first, then .selected property must work well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// is it checked? 
var isChecked = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@type='checkbox']").Selected;
```

Using the `.Selected` attribute should achieve what you are trying to do. The reason I add the `driver.FindElement` statement is to ensure you are locating the correct element -- based on your problem description, I'm not sure if the element you located & tested against was the correct one.

As another user pointed out, if `GetAttribute("class")` returns `slider round`, then you are looking at the wrong element here. Ensure the `input` element has been located first.

Your XPath at your file header `//*[@id='divTestAcc']/div[1]/p[9]/label/span` will locate the `span` element, not the `input` -- `input` is the one with `checked`, so that's what we need to test against.

Comment: Thank you ! This has worked, i have been stuck on this for days but that solves the issue and returns true when checked and false when not checked! YES!